# Can using media query with CSS ::after & ::before tag?

Tags: css, css-selectors, media-queries

I used an after tag to show custom content in the pricing table. It really works with the desktop screen But does not show on mobile. How can I add media queries to it?

```
.wrc_pricing_table span.price_desc::after  
{
  content: "  year " !important;
  font-size:16px !important;
}
    }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
  .wrc_pricing_table span.price_desc::after  
{
  content: "  changed text " !important;
  font-size:14px !important;
}
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @aman.Is it working with the WordPress platform? I used it for a WordPress website.still not showing content in a mobile view?

Comment: obviously it worked, with any platform! you need to show what you tried in your website, may there is any other cause, without graphical representation we just imagine.